# Redirecting multiple values in URL with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm trying to get Greasemonkey to automatically redirect a page when it hits a certain URL, and redirect to a page with two of the same values. For instance:

http://www.google.com/page=438985&view=49834
into: http://www.google.com/document/page=438985/field&view=49834&DONE

I've tried the following:

```
var links,thisLink;
links = document.evaluate("//a[@href]",
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null);

for (var i=0;i<links.snapshotLength;i++) {
    var thisLink = links.snapshotItem(i);

    thisLink.href = thisLink.href.replace(RegExp('http://www.google.com/page=($1)&view=($2)'),
                                          'http://www.google.com/document/page=$1/field&view=$2&DONE');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = links.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(links[i] && links[i].href) {
        links[i].href = links[i].href.replace(/http:\/\/www\.google\.com\/page=(\d+)&view=(\d+)/,
                        'http://www.google.com/document/page=$1/field&view=$2&DONE');
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t83v73tw/)